# Difficulties installing apache web-server on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, software-installation, apache2

I was wondering if I can get some assistance here to install an apache2 web-server on my Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed the instructions, such as : opening the terminal, and typing : `sudo apt-get update`, then press "enter".

I receive the following message : `password`. Which password is it referring to ?
I really need help.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your group membership to make certain you're using an account capable of making changes to the system.  For example...

```
richard@XubHome:~$ groups
richard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev sambashare lpadmin
```

If you show as being a member of the **sudo** group, simply entering your account password again should initiate the changes you are attempting to make.

Best success...

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to the password for the user you set up when you installed Ubuntu.